# How to parse a URL string with multiple parameter values?

Tags: asp.net, .net, parsing, url

I'm making this oddball webservice that gets its parameters as query parameters in the URL. Problem is, that a single parameter can have multiple values. Similar to:

```
http://mydomain/Service?operation=ActivateUser&id=1&id=2&id=3
```

In this case I need to activate 3 users with ID's 1, 2 and 3. Even worse, it could be like this (I think, the spec is a bit vague, will clarify later):

```
http://mydomain/Service?operation=ActivateUser&id=1&operation=DeleteUser&id=2
```

In this case I need to activate user 1 and delete user 2.

So I really need a URL parser which preserves the order of the parameters. .NET's default `Request.QueryString` doesn't do that, it just separates the values by commas and to hell with order.

Short of diving in and splitting the raw URL by ?, & and = myself, is there a better way?

Comment: Could you change delimiters?  eg. op=ActivateUser&ids=1|2|3?

Comment: No, unfortunately this representation is forced upon me.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like `Request.QueryString.GetValues` (which is [NameValueCollection.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ba5htte.aspx))is what you're after. It will return a string array of the values it finds for a given key and in the order they are in the url..

Given http://www.site.com/page.aspx?keyid=1&keyid=2&keyid=3

```
string[] keys = Request.QueryString.GetValues("keyid");

keys[0] would be "1"
keys[1] would be "2"
keys[2] would be "3"
```

Comment: Nice! The only problem now could be in my second example. Will see next week if it is a real problem or not.

Comment: @Vilx- Should be okay still. You'd have to check separately for the operation querystring, and then I assume you would act upon the 2nd item in the array.

Comment: But if there are 2 values for the "operation" and 4 values for "id", how do I know which ids go to which operation?

Comment: @Vilx- Ahh. Gotcha. Didn't read that as a possibility with multiple operations. That one may be more difficult. May have to manually parse at that point.